# TYPO3 findByProperty doesn't work

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I've got an repository with prueflings objects.

so I want to do a search action like this

```
$pruefling = $this->prueflingRepository->findByMatrikelnr($matrikelnr);
```

Each pruefling in prueflingRepository has an variable matrikelnr

but if i try to do the request like above i've got
    Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

In the repository are only 3 elements at the moment

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cache cleared and it works! Sorry for asking!